# Passing variable to pause command in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

How can I pass variable to pause command and use this variable with pause command in other parts of test suite in Selenium IDE? I want to define time variable at the begining of test suite and use that time variable in other parts of test suite like following.

```
pause $variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Init variable via  "store" command. Attention: Value = variablename
Read variable via ${variablename}

Example:
[image: Selenium IDE script with pauseBetween as variable]

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old now but here goes anyway.

I find I have to store as variable

```
{
      "id": "bbbb21d6-4fab-42df-bdd9-896e94bd4d59",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "executeScript",
      "target": "return (${i} * 100)",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "pausems"
    },
```

Then when to use in the pause command, don't use the ${VariableName} syntax, but instead reference the variable as follows; 'vars.VariableName'

```
 {
      "id": "b65554de-c1f2-494d-bad0-935247b6febc",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "pause",
      "target": "vars.pausems",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question centers more around method parameters, scope, and access within your program which are not Selenium specific.  That being said, you should go look at some tutorials on Java, [here](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/).

With regards to creating a Pause class, you will want to look at the Robot class, [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/54172-robot-class/).

But, be warned, using Robot to accommodate delays in the web page loading is a hack at best and prone to failure.  I suggest you investigate implicit waits and using Robot only as a buffer or a last resort.

Waits are explained [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: Am I missing something? The OP states that he is running Selenium IDE.

Comment: Yes, it is Selenium IDE. Do you suggest another solution with selenium IDE?